# bootstrap 4 interior column spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Fairly new to design and coding, and working on my first freeCodeCamp project. Anyway, I have a row that's divided into three medium columns like so:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 pb-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 pb-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 pb-3"></div>
</div>
```

The `pb-3` class is just to add some padding below each item for mobile. Anyway, each column has a YouTube video embedded in it. On desktop, the padding on the outside edges of the outer columns is just right, but there's too much padding BETWEEN the columns, presumably because each column is providing its own padding, so the padding is doubled. I've tried tweaking the padding to fix this, but the problem is that if I give different columns different padding, the YouTube content is resized and looks wonky.

[Here's the link to the full CodePen](https://codepen.io/sethwilsonUS/pen/vmMExW) if anyone wants to take a closer look.

Thanks!

~Seth~

Comment: I suppose you could customize the gutter spacing in the grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Comment: btw, it is recommended to include a [mcve] to your question. Links can be unavailable at any given time making the question incomplete and thus, impossible to answer.